# Adding values that don't exist in SELECT statement output

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I am not sure how to ask this, due to my lack of experience, so please bear with me.

I am using a `SELECT` statement to extract pending applications (i.e. no completed date) and `count`ing their totals (plus some other counting).  There are certain project types that I need to gather from, 8 of them, where only 4 of them currently have a pending application.  I still need to show the other project types with a 0 in the count column.  If I try to union with a query that will pull all data, pending or not, I get duplicate rows (minus the count columns) for the 4 project types with currently pending applications.  If I left join to the project type table, I get a null row.  Neither are what I want.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Output of the union:

```
General Construction       0    0       90    0
General Coverage           0    0       90    0
General Coverage           1    740     90    90
General Renewal            0    0       90    0
Individual Construction    0    0       90    0
Individual Coverage        0    0       180   0
Individual Renewal         0    0       90    0
Individual Renewal         2    1027    90    180
Approval                   0    0       90    0
Approval                   22   565     90    1980
Other - Renewal            0    0       90    0
Other - Renewal            21   1119    90    1890
```

Output without the necessary '0' rows:

```
General Coverage           1    740     90    90
Individual Renewal         2    1027    90    180
Other - Renewal            21   1119    90    1890
Approval                   22   566     90    1980
```

Output that I would like to see is:

```
    General Construction        0   0    90    0
    General Coverage            1   740  90    90
    General Renewal             0   0    90    0
    Individual Construction     0   0    90    0
    Individual Coverage         0   0    180   0
    Individual Renewal          2   1027 90    180
    Approval                    22  565  90    1980
    Other - Renewal             21  1119 90    1890
```

Please let me know what else I can provide to help you help me.

Comment: What is the output that you want? Adding sample tables/data would be nice also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide names of your columns or anything like that.

What you need is a driver table with all valid values.  You can then use `left outer join` to get the result set you want:

```
select driver.val, coalesce(q.col2, 0), coalesce(q.col3, 0), coalesce(q.col4, 0)
from (select 'General Construction' as val from dual union all
      select 'General Coverage'  as val from dual union all
      select 'General Renewal'  as val from dual union all
      select 'Individual Construction' as val from dual union all
      select 'Individual Coverage'  as val from dual union all
      select 'Individual Renewal' as val from dual union all
      select 'Approval' as val from dual union all
      select 'Other - Renewal' as val from dual
     ) driver left outer join
     (query without 0 rows) q
     on driver.val = q.col1
```

If NULLs are okay instead of 0s, then the `coalesce()` is not needed.

Comment: You rock, @Gordon Linoff! That was exactly what I needed.  I'm sorry I was so vague.  A lot of the data I work with is proprietary and I try to get away without using actual data or column names if I can. Thanks again!